# How to run multiple objects of a class having a function calling only threads in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a subclass called **WiFiControlImplementation** , it is a subclass of another class called **WifiSniffer**

The WiFiControlImplementation contains a public method:

```
class WiFiControlImplementation : public WifiSniffer {
    public:
       WiFiControlImplementation(){};
       void startControlProcess (void);
    private:
       bool callback            (void) override;
```

and it inherits two functions from WifiSniffer :

```
class WifiSniffer{
    public:
       WifiSniffer(){};
       void  run                (void);
       void  runChannelHop      (int hopscale);
    private:
       virtual bool callback         (void);
```

The function startControlProcess must run the two inherited functions in separate threads:

```
void WiFiControlImplementation::startControlProcess(){
   std::thread channelhop  (&WiFiControlImplementation::runChannelHop,this,3);
   std::thread runner      (&WiFiControlImplementation::run,this);
}
```

Now how to do if I want to run the object in another main file (example: main.cpp)?
Do I do this :

```
   #include "wifi_ControlImplementation.h"
   int main(int argc, char **argv){
      WiFiControlImplementation job;
      job.startControlProcess();
      while(1){}; // For not stopping the main thread so that the object thread can still run ?
   }
```

And how should I do it if I want to run multiple objects of the same class like this:

```
   #include "wifi_ControlImplementation.h"
   int main(int argc, char **argv){
      WiFiControlImplementation job;
      job.startControlProcess();

      WiFiControlImplementation job2;
      job2.startControlProcess();

      WiFiControlImplementation job3;
      job3.startControlProcess();
      while(1){};
   }
```

Comment: Hi serialback, welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried running the code you posted? If so, what happens?

Comment: `while(1){};` no, you shouldn't do that. What does it ever mean?

Comment: When I run the program without while(1) , the program exits with terminate " called without an active exception
Aborted" problem , because the main function is calling an object which have a function running only threads, so the main program is only running threads and exits, and if the main program exits the threads will be killed , right ? How should I fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run class functions in threads from a main program , I just used a function for each one of them, and the second function returns a thread that executes the first function in a lambda call, here is the example :

- In **wifi_Hopper.h** :

```
#include <thread>
class wifi_Hopper {
     public:
        wifi_Hopper(){};
        std::thread start_thread(void) {
            return std::thread( [=] { start_hopping(); } );
        }
     private:
        void start_hopping(void);
}
```

- In **main.cpp** :

```
#include "wifi_Hopper.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv){
   wifi_Hopper wH;
   std::thread HopperThread = wH.start_thread();
   HopperThread.join();
   return 0;
}
```

- And you can define many functions in one class and make a thread-return function for each one, and you can call all of them with the same object of the class.